# GraphQL test schema and resolvers

Tags: graphql

**WHAT I TRIED**
I am using JEST for testing resolvers and schema but I am having trouble in creating folder and structure.Currently I import resolver functions and call functions and compare result or check if fields are defined.But it does not sometimes satisfy complex scenarios.

**WHAT I AM LOOKING FOR**

The best practices to test graphql schema and resolver functions, and what testing tool is recommended or mostly used?

Comment: What kind of tests are you looking for? My feeling with GraphQL is that only integration tests are really worth it because if you write unit tests you write hundreds of lines of code to create a mock environment to test 1 line of code (at least this is the average length of a resolver in our code).

Comment: Yes I am more focused on **intergration testing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple frameworks out there for integration testing your API using for example YAML files. There you can specify request and response. A simpler approach can be to use Jest snapshots and simply execute test queries using the `graphql` function from `graphql-js`. It will return a promise with the result and you can then `await` it and expect it to match the snapshot.

```
import { graphql } from 'graphql';
import schema from './schema';
import createContext from './createContext';

describe('GraphQL Schema', () => {
  let context;

  before(() => {
    context = createContext();
    database.setUp();
  });

  after(() => {
    database.tearDown();
  });

  it('should resolve simple query', async () => {
    const query = '{ hello }';
    const result = await graphql(schema, query, null, context);

    expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Tipp: You can also create dynamic tests for example by reading queries from files in a directory and then iterating over them creating a new test for each file. An example for that (not GraphQL though) can be [found on my Github](https://github.com/setlxjs/setlxjs-transpiler/blob/master/test/integration/index.test.js).

Comment: Thanks buddy it helps.

Comment: the repo is out of date. And your example is not escalable.

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can try this npm package that will test your Schema, Queries and Mutations... there is an example of it using mocha & chai.. here is the [link](https://github.com/EasyGraphQL/easygraphql-tester#easygraphql-tester-with-mocha--chai)

What you need to do, is import the schema and pass to the `easygraphql-tester` and then you can create UT.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a recomendable way to do it. Specially for documents and folder structure.

In my case, I am working on this [repo](https://github.com/josuevalrob/cle_api).  And this is my folder structure in the first level:

```
src/
├── App.js
├── configs
├── helpers
├── index.js
├── middlewares
├── models
├── resolvers
├── routes
├── schema
├── seeds
├── templates
├── tests
└── utils
```

In the root, I have the test folder, mainly to checkout the App basic behavior and some utils functions. In the other hand, inside the resolvers i have the main test for the GraphQl, queries and mutations.

```
src/resolvers/
├── camping
│   ├── camping.mutations.js
│   ├── camping.query.js
│   ├── camping.query.test.js
│   └── camping.resolver.js
├── clientes.resolver.js
├── guest
│   ├── guest.mutation.js
│   ├── guest.mutation.test.js
│   ├── guest.query.js
│   ├── guest.query.test.js
│   └── guest.resolver.js
├── index.js
├── turno
│   ├── turno.mutations.js
│   ├── turno.query.js
│   ├── turno.query.test.js
│   └── turno.resolver.js
└── users
    ├── user.mutations.js
    ├── user.mutations.test.js
    ├── user.queries.js
    ├── user.query.test.js
    └── user.resolver.js
```

Every single resolver has his test, you can check there if the basic endpoints are working as expected.

I am planning to do some workflow tests, they will be in the test root folder later.